# According to official FIDE rules, when queening a pawn, can you pause the clock?

Tags: rules, pawn-promotion

I have heard that you are allowed to pause to clock to find your queen. Is this true?

Comment: Wasn't there a Karpov-Kasparov match where this was an issue?  Kasparov didn't stop the clock while waiting for a piece, and that gave Karpov extra time or something?

Answer (score 8):

You may stop the clock if the piece that you wish to promote to is not at hand:

> 6.12.b. A player may stop the chessclock only in order to seek the arbiter’s assistance, for example when promotion has taken place and
>   the piece required is not available.